# I have a MongoDB connection error when I try to deploy my application on any hosting server, but my app work on my machine

Tags: render.com

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:829:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:804:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async connectDB (/opt/render/project/src/config/database.js:5:18) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-mwbqrb7-shard-00-00.ysfsjei.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-mwbqrb7-shard-00-01.ysfsjei.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-mwbqrb7-shard-00-02.ysfsjei.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-oquqci-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
```

Comment: I assume that the Render hosting platform has a firewall that is stopping connections going out. Do you have a control panel there to allow 27017 outbound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

When you create new cluster, Mongo Atlas will add your IP into whitelist. So your machine can connect to it. If you want any machine can access to your Mongo Atlas, you can set 0.0.0.0/0 into whitelist (as picture attachment).